# Create one or more shiny widgets based on selection of another shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which the user may select between one or more column names from the dt data.frame

```
name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
value1<-c(2,4,6)
add<-c("SDF","GHK","FGH")
value2<-c(3,4,5)
dt<-data.frame(name,value1,add,value2)
```

Then for every selection he makes the relative `selectInput()` may be displayed below. Maybe I could use `if` for every case but the issue is that my real dataset may be much bigger and has different column names every time so Im looking for a way to instantly connect the `pickerInput()` selected name with the creation of the relative `selectInput()` which will include the column values. For example if someone select all 4 column names 4 selectInputs should be created with the relative column name as label.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# ui object
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "p1",
                label = "Select Column headers",
                choices = colnames( dt),
                multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
            ),
            uiOutput("widg")
            
            
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            
        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
   
    output$widg<-renderUI({
        
    })
    
   
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

High level, I would create the `selectInput` in the statically in the UI and consider using `updateSelectInput` when your picker changes. Roughly something like this (note the addition of the `session` variable to the server function):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "Select Column headers",
        choices = colnames( dt),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      selectInput("columnValues", "", choices = "")
      
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      inputId = "columnValues", 
      label = paste0("Choose from: ", input$p1),
      choices = dt[[input$p1]]
    )
    
  })
  
  
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I did notice you are using a multi-select picker so you would have to modify how the column values get concatenated when multiple headers are chosen (also how the label is generated).

If you don't want to `selectInput` to be visible if nothing is selected in the picker, there are multiple ways to toggle its visibility such as using `conditionalPanel`.

Comment: when I try to select a second value it breaks down

Comment: Yep, which is why `label` and `choices` need to be modified. I wasn't sure what the desired behavior was. Could be something like `purrr::reduce(input$p1, ~c(.x, dt[[.y]]), .init = NULL)`. Or are you saying you want the number of selectInputs to vary depending on which headers are chosen?

Comment: If you're looking for the latter, take a look at this article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: yes I would like a solution with the 2nd. if I select 4 i d like a solution with 4 selectinputs

Comment: The label should be the same with the column name

Comment: Im nor sure how to adapt your suggestion. Could you help?